# Flickering on desktop environment, No StandBy

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, hybrid-graphics

I installed a ubuntu 18.04 on my HP Probook G5 (Intel i7-8550U, GeForce 930MX). I noticed a strange flickering on the display.

- I get strong tearing in glxheads
- I get this flickering on cinammon and gnome
- I installed the proprietary nvidia driver
- I cannot recover from sleep, the screen shows a blinking `_` then it fades to black. I can't get it to a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F*`
- (**Edit**) Scaling down the resolution seems to help

I have another Notebook Lenovo Think Pad (Intel i7-8550U, GeForce 150MX), which had the same flickering, but it was gone after installing the proprietary driver.

The output of `lswh -c video` show that the nvidia driver is enabled:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:1f0-1ef iomemory:1f0-1ef irq:132 memory:1ff0000000-1ff0ffffff memory:1fe0000000-1fefffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:144 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

Any idea what causing the display flickering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the newest Kernel (18.5). Now all the problems are gone:

- Standby works flawlessly
- No flickering on screen
- No blurry text on parts of the screen